# Would giving a swordsage the Iron Heart discipline unbalance him?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

I am not really fond of disciplines with magical effects, like Desert Wind (Shadow Hand is in the same category, but let's face it, it has maneuvers called Shadow Jaunt, Shadow Blink, and something similar to a force choke).

I really like the Iron Heart maneuvers, and it's fluff (martial perfection, etc. etc.), but i have a doubt as to whether trading Desert Wind for Iron Heart would unbalance things.

Comment: Alternativelly, would master of the nine worth taking, for swordsage 15/MoN5, just to get some 9 lvl maneuvers, and some Iron Heart ones?

Comment: If you're a strength based person, why not go warblade?

Comment: Dm does not allow warblade, and the truth is that i really like the sage in swordsage (hate the wannabe magic understanding though).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you swap them, you would disrupt the balance of disciplines between the three base classes (Crusaders, Swordsages and Warblades); it is designed for them to have unique abilities when compared to the others. However, since your DM doesn't allow Warblades and Crusaders don't have Iron Heart you can argue it doesn't really matter much. (It's pretty weird for someone to disallow that one but allow other ToB classes, though. Are you totally sure SS is okay with him? Also check that starting availability of Iron Heart isn't why he banned it in the first place.)